# Keep a user logged in to React Native app forever

Tags: security, express, react-native, jwt

I'm trying to work out the best way to keep users logged in to my RN app once they've logged in, until they uninstall the app.

I'm using a Node/Express back end that accepts a JWT with every request and my only plan at the moment is to send a never expiring JWT on log in and store it permanently using AsyncStorage.

This instinctively feels unsafe, but I'm no expert in security and tokens. I'm using Expo to get my RN app off the ground at the moment but in the future I plan to "eject" it and once I do I can store it more securely using react-native-keychain but it'll still be a JWT that never expires.

My spotify app never asks me to log back in, so I know what I'm trying to do is not crazy.

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use long-term **JWT** since they can be cracked easily if the **secret keys** used are weak or short.

There are some of the libraries available which might help you track the bruteforce duration under which **JWT** can be cracked, such as [`jwt-cracker`](https://github.com/lmammino/jwt-cracker), [`c-jwt-cracker`](https://github.com/brendan-rius/c-jwt-cracker).

Therefore you should use the [**SecureStore**](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v29.0.0/sdk/securestore) already available in the **Expo SDK**.
*IOS* values are stored using the [keychain services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) and *Android* values are stored in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), encrypted with [Android's Keystore system](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html).

If there is an error in the **API**, that uses a token, you can simply make a call to either *reauthenticate* or *refresh* it using **Interceptors**

Comment: OK, so I didn't know that Expo had a secure way of storing alues, I'll certainly switch to that. I don't understand the last bit though, what are interceptors and how do I "refresh" a JWT?

Comment: Interceptors intercept the api calls. It captures `request` and `response` objects before or after api call. If the api call fails you can call the api which either refreshes the token or reauthenticates. You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/werk85/fetch-intercept)

Comment: Ah, response interceptors, I can do that in Axios, I guess I just need an endpoint that can take an expired token and send back a new one. If it always returns a new token from an expired one then how is that different from a never expiring token?

Comment: It would generate a new hash everytime based on the payload which would be difficult to crack, in comparison to long term generated jwt